# Is it possible for there to be a mechanical way in which one would prove a tautology (in a propositional calculus)

Tags: propositional-calculus

Basically is there any algorithm for proving a tautology? (even if it runs in exponential time?)

Additionally, is it possible for a propositional calculus to be such that a tautology is presented in a way in which it is clear that it is a tautology (so that, just by looking at it one would see it is a tautology?

Comment: It is possible, because the propositional calculus is decidable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a few methods: truth tables, axiomatic (or "Hilbert-style") systems, natural deduction, and others. The method of truth tables is probably the easiest to prove complete and correct, and it runs in exponential time at worst (the problem is actually [co-NP complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP-complete)).

I'm not sure what your additional question asks. Any formal system for propositional logic has only finitely many axioms or axiom schemas (e.g. "$(A\to(B\to A))$ is an axiom, for any well-formed formulas $A, B$") and finitely many deduction rules. It's usually clear that the axioms/axiom schemas/starting set of truths are tautologies, and for formulas of human-friendly lengths, we can usually see whether they're instances. But tautologies can be arbitrarily long. Given notations currently in use, for formulas longer than some threshold (say, $10^{10}$ symbols), there's no way anyone can see if a formula is a tautology just by looking at it.

Comment: Kind of off point, but is the truth-table method considered a propositional proof system (in the eyes of computer scientists) if proofs can only be done in exponential time?  In regards to the second question of my OP, what I was asking is if it's possible for there to be some system in which tautologies have some feature which makes them instantly recognizable as tautologies

Comment: @Stacked It's definitely an algorithm, even if it only turns out to run in (nothing better than) exponential time. In computer science the problem 3SAT, satisfiability for propositional formulas with 3 variables, is NP-complete. The dual problem of $n$-SAT is $n$-VALID, whether a formula in $n$ variables is a tautology. Clearly the problem is in the complexity class EXP — the standard brute-force method shows that — but actually we can do a little better: the problem of recognizing tautologies is co-NP complete. I added a little to clarify this.

Comment: Re your 2nd question: I suppose you could, for example, "tag" all formulas that the system generates/derives with an extra symbol up front. What sort of features did you have in mind? This and others like it wouldn't help much: we'd still have the problem of looking at an ordinary formula, without the new decoration(s), and determining whether its decorated version is provable :)

Comment: More precise/correct version of 1st line of my 2nd to last comment: It's definitely an algorithm, although it runs in exponential time. That just means it's not a feasible algorithm for anything except small-ish problems. Maybe there is a better deterministic algorithm for recognizing tautologies, but at present we don't know enough about the class co-NP to say.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: I believe so. Thanks

Comment: "Yes, there are a few methods: truth tables, axiomatic (or "Hilbert-style") systems, natural deduction, and others."  Axiomatic systems don't provide an algorithm for proofs from the axioms.  And what if the propositional calculus only has infinite valued models, such as Lukasiewicz infinite-valued logic?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood re axiomatic system. True, they're not algorithms, of course. I didn't want to get too verbose. An axiomatic system + a program that systematically generates all consequences of a set of premises *does* give an algorithm. It's safe to assume that "propositional calculus" as intended by OP does not mean or even encompass infinite-valued propositional logic.

Answer (score 1):

Truth tables can get converted into a set of equations which exhaustively cover all possible truth-value assignments for a given well-formed formula.  Those equations can get transformed into steps in a substitution and detachment proof in a system for a propositional calculus with functorial variables.  For details of how this works see [here](http://dougspoonwood.blogspot.com/2014/10/the-following-gives-us-proof-of.html#comment-form) or p. 65-66 of Arthur Prior's *Formal Logic*.

So, there exists an algorithm for proving any *finite-valued* tautology.

Comment: "However, there is no algorithm for proving a given well-formed formula from a set of formulas and a set of rules. "  Would it be interesting if there was one, even if it was grossly inefficient? Or is it not thought to be possible, regardless of being efficient or not?

Comment: @Stacked I take that back about no algorithm existing for formal proofs.  There often enough does exist the possibility of doing what can get called a level saturation search.  It depends on what we want to prove as to whether that comes as interesting or not.  Often enough a level saturation search isn't all that interesting, though it can be.